# How to insert_many preventing duplicate records where a key other than _id is considered as primary key?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have an existing MongoDB collection where each document is like -

```
{
    "_id":"5e7467b76fbf38cd13c4f322",
    "Revision":"HEXDEF",
    "Variant":"2800",
}
```

I want to use insert_many to insert an array of form say -

```
data = [
    {
        "Revision":"ABXDEF",
        "Variant":"1800",
    },
    {
        "Revision":"HEXDEF",
        "Variant":"2400",
    }
]
```

Here I consider Revision as my Primary key and doesn't want to insert a record with that Revison if it already exist. What is the right way to achieve this?

Currently my MongoDB Query is -

```
db[collection].insert_many(data)
```

Comment: Have you considered a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices; either use the _id in place of revision or create a unique index. I prefer the latter approach. This code sample may help:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.create_index('Revision', unique=True)
data = [
    {
        "Revision":"ABXDEF",
        "Variant":"1800",
    },
    {
        "Revision":"HEXDEF",
        "Variant":"2400",
    },
    {
        "Revision": "ABXDEF",
        "Variant": "2700",
    },
    {
        "Revision": "ZZZZZZ",
        "Variant": "3000",
    }
]

# ordered=True (default) will stop writing on an error (only 2 records added)
# ordered=False will continue after with any subsequent inserts after the error
try:
    result = db.mycollection.insert_many(data, ordered=True)
    print (f'All ok - {result.nInserted} records inserted')
except BulkWriteError as e:
    writeErrors = e.details.get('writeErrors')
    print (f"{len(writeErrors)} WriteErrors and {e.details.get('nInserted')} records inserted")
    print(writeErrors)
```